# Access a member of a class in c#?

Tags: c#, razor

I used MvcScaffolding to create CRUD files for me. I have this cs class:

```
    public class addresses
{
    /* Some code */
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; } /* I need to access this */
    public DateTime date_modified { get; set; } /* And this */
}
```

and I need to access the `date_created` variable. I want to access it in either the controller that was created for me (c#) or the `_CreateOrEdit.cshtml` file that was created. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

I want to access it in here for example

```
    public class addressesController : Controller
{
    private SoccerContext context = new SoccerContext();

    //
    // GET: /addresses/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
```

**I want to access it here to set it to current time**

```
        ViewBag.PossibleUsers = context.users;
        ViewBag.PossibleContacts = context.contacts;
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /addresses/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(addresses addresses)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.addresses.Add(addresses);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        ViewBag.PossibleUsers = context.users;
        ViewBag.PossibleContacts = context.contacts;
        return View(addresses);
    }
    //More code............
```

Comment: This should work. Are you getting any errors in code using it?

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors but I want to access that `public DateTime date_created` in another part of my code so that I can set it to the current time.

Comment: @Andy, then please show the other part of your code.  We can't help you access something without understanding what your context is.

Comment: `date_created` isn't a global variable, it's a property of `addresses` objects. Said another part of code needs to get its hands on such an object somehow. (My guess is you need to work through tutorials more.)

Comment: @KirkWoll sorry I've posted an edit.

Comment: I still don't see where you're trying to access `date_created`.

Comment: @millimoose Yes I know its not a global variable. I wan't to access that property and don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access like this:

```
var addr = new addresses();
var created = addr.date_created;
//same for date_modofied
```